# Reference Swift enum member without its associated value

Tags: swift, enums

I have the following enum:

```
enum State: Equatable {
    case Loading
    case Finished
    case Error(message: String)
}

func ==(lhs: State, rhs: State) -> Bool {
    //...
}
```

I want to be able to compare enum members. I have overloaded `==` operator, and it works, but there's a problem:

```
let state: State = .Loading

// works just fine
let thisWorks = state == .Finished 

// this does as well
let thisWorks2 = state == .Error("Derp!")

// this, however, does not, compiler error: "Could not find member 'Error'"
let thisDoesnt = state == .Error
```

This seems to be a compiler limitation. I don't see why I should not be able to reference the enum member without its associated value. Apparently I don't care about the error message associated with `.Error`, I just need to know if an error has occurred. This is actually possible with `switch`, so I don't know why regular statements are limited.

I have to admit that I haven't looked at Swift 2 closely. Should I expect some improvements in the new version? Another question is, until it is released, is there any workaround?

Comment: Have you tried `.Error(_)`? The `_` is a wild card and effectively will discard/ignore whatever value it matches.

Comment: @AndrewMonshizadeh compiler says `'_' can only appear in a pattern or on the left side of an assignment`

Comment: I forgot the `message:` before the underscore. Not at my computer so can't check for sure. Should be similar to @matteo's edit below

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Enums work really well with `switch`:

```
let state: State = .Error(message: "Foo")

switch state {
case .Loading:
    print("Loading")
case .Finished:
    print("Finished")
case .Error(message: "Foo"):
    print("Foo!!!")
case .Error(message: _):
    print("Some other error")
}
```

Swift 2.0 will bring another control flow syntax that probably you will appreciate:

### Swift 2.0

```
if case .Error(message: _) = state {
    print("An Error")
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: By the way, in the example above, you do not need to implement `==`

Comment: No disagreement, they do. They are designed to. But it's really awkward when you have to mix the enum member comparison with other boolean condition in, say, an if statement.

Comment: Edited with an addition from **Switf 2.0**. Meanwhile I would simply stick whit the canonical `switch` pattern. It will be easier updating it later when Swift 2.0 will be released.

Comment: In the switch-statement you can just write `case .Error: ...` and in Swift 2  `if case .Error = state { ... }` if you don't care about the associated value.

Comment: @MartinR More verbous than just `state == .Error`, but will do, I guess.

Comment: Shouldn't the swift 2 version be `if case .Error(message: _) == state` (comparison, not assignment.)

Comment: @DuncanC maybe it could be `~=` which is intended as _pattern match_. But as for now it is `=`. We are still in beta, it could change ;-)

Comment: @deville as of now I wold also consider defining a custom `~=` operator since it is typically used for _pattern match_ (which is what appears you do). `~=` could simply encapsulate the switch logic.

Comment: @MatteoPiombo If I understand your idea correctly, I would still have to write `state ~= .Error` and get the same compiler error as with `==`

Comment: Yep, just avoiding some possible confusion. `.Error(message: "Foo")` is not, strictly speaking, `==` to `.Error(message: "Bar")`. But the two _pattern match_ with `.Error(message: "")`. You save `Equatable` for what it is really intended to, and just in case you need it. Then if Swift 2.0 will be better for your needs, you can easily refactor it, without side effects deriving from the use of `==` for what is a pattern match.

Answer (score 0):

You are creating a new instance of the enum. You're error enum has a **required** associated value. It can't be nil. Thus when you create an enum, you must give it a value.

How about if you make your error state's associated value optional?

```
enum State: Equatable {
    case Loading
    case Finished
    case Error(message: String?)
```

Then you could use code like this:

```
let thisDoesnt = state == .Error(nil)
```

Comment: This is the solution for Swift 1.2. But I guess I'd rather keep the value non-optional and initialize with `""` to avoid unwrapping.

Comment: Why is this only a solution for Swift 1.2? Do you mean Swift < 2.0, or do you mean Swift 1.2, not Swift 1.1?

Comment: yeah, I meant < 2.0, of course. I wonder if anyone still uses the older versions (< 1.2)

Answer (score -1):

Try it.

```
let thisWorks2 = state == .Error(message: "Derp!");
```